# Returning DocuSign Customer Data field values

Tags: xml, docusignapi

Is there a way to get data values entered into a DocuSign document custom field returned with the document(s)?  We are using the SOAP API interface to DocuSign and will be sending in documents and XML that request the recipient/signer to enter data into fields (data entry, check boxes, radio buttons, etc.)

From our research it appears that DocuSign returns the documents and data as a PDF, but we want to also have the data sent back in the XML response from DocuSign.

It appears there is an additional call to DocuSign named "GetEnvelopeCustomField" to retieve this data but we are not sure how this call works.  Cannot seem to find much information on the call.

If anyone has done this or has any advice I would appreciate any feedback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are API calls to do this in both SOAP and REST.  In SOAP just make the `RequestEnvelope` call, and that will return all info about the envelope including documents, recipients, and tabs.  For instance, part of the response coming back would contain something like this:

```
<Tabs>
      <Tab>
        <DocumentID>positiveInteger</DocumentID>
        <RecipientID>positiveInteger</RecipientID>
        <PageNumber>nonNegativeInteger</PageNumber>
        <XPosition>nonNegativeInteger</XPosition>
        <YPosition>nonNegativeInteger</YPosition>
        <ScaleValue>decimal</ScaleValue>
        <AnchorTabItem xsi:nil="true" />
        <Type>InitialHere or SignHere or FullName or FirstName or LastName or EmailAddress or Company or Title or DateSigned or InitialHereOptional or EnvelopeID or Custom or SignerAttachment or SignHereOptional or Approve or Decline or SignerAttachmentOptional</Type>
        <Name>string</Name>
        <TabLabel>string</TabLabel>

        <Value>string</Value>

        <CustomTabType>Text or Checkbox or Radio or List or Date or Number or SSN or ZIP5 or ZIP5DASH4 or Email or Note or Formula</CustomTabType>
        <CustomTabWidth>int</CustomTabWidth>
        <CustomTabHeight>int</CustomTabHeight>
        <CustomTabRequired>boolean</CustomTabRequired>
        <CustomTabLocked>boolean</CustomTabLocked>
        <CustomTabDisableAutoSize>boolean</CustomTabDisableAutoSize>
        <CustomTabListItems>string</CustomTabListItems>
        <CustomTabListValues>string</CustomTabListValues>
        <CustomTabListSelectedValue>string</CustomTabListSelectedValue>
        <CustomTabRadioGroupName>string</CustomTabRadioGroupName>
        <CustomTabValidationPattern>string</CustomTabValidationPattern>
        <CustomTabValidationMessage>string</CustomTabValidationMessage>
        <TemplateLocked>boolean</TemplateLocked>
        <TemplateRequired>boolean</TemplateRequired>
        <ConditionalParentLabel>string</ConditionalParentLabel>
        <ConditionalParentValue>string</ConditionalParentValue>
        <SharedTab>boolean</SharedTab>
        <RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>boolean</RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>
        <ConcealValueOnDocument>boolean</ConcealValueOnDocument>
        <Font>Arial or ArialNarrow or Calibri or CourierNew or Garamond or Georgia or Helvetica or LucidaConsole or Tahoma or TimesNewRoman or Trebuchet or Verdana</Font>
        <Bold>boolean</Bold>
        <Italic>boolean</Italic>
        <Underline>boolean</Underline>
        <FontColor>Black or BrightBlue or BrightRed or DarkRed or DarkGreen or Gold or Green or NavyBlue or Purple or White</FontColor>
        <FontSize>Size7 or Size8 or Size9 or Size10 or Size11 or Size12 or Size14 or Size16 or Size18 or Size20 or Size22 or Size24 or Size26 or Size28 or Size36 or Size48 or Size72</FontSize>
        <MergeFieldXml>string</MergeFieldXml>
        <IncludeNoteInEmail>boolean</IncludeNoteInEmail>
        <IsPaymentAmount>boolean</IsPaymentAmount>
        <Formula>string</Formula>
        <RoundDecimalPlaces>int</RoundDecimalPlaces>
        <MaxLength>int</MaxLength>
        <SenderRequired>boolean</SenderRequired>
      </Tab>
  </Tabs>
```

You just need to parse the XML and retrieve whichever values you're interested in.  Here is the schema of the `RequestEnvelope` call:

https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?op=RequestEnvelope